# PySide 6 snake_case does not autocomplete everything

Tags: autocomplete, ide, pyside6, snakecasing

I would like to use the snake_case feature from pyside6. I have the code working but I'd like to have my IDE autocomplete the methods as snake_case as well.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67206894/how-does-the-new-snake-case-feature-work-in-pyside6/73046076#73046076) discussing the issue, and the answer linking to [this QT page](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/feature-why.html) explaining the feature and how to use it. Following that I executed `pyside6-genpyi all --feature snake_case true_property` which resolved a lot of the methods, but not all. For example, `set_window_title` or `button.set_text` are not recognised by the IDE, while `set_central_widget` and `set_fixed_size` do get resolved.

How can I get my IDE to recognise all the Qt methods as snake_case?

Comment: 1. Are you sure that the unresolved methods are not actually from dynamically created objects? 2. Are you *really* sure about using that feature? Besides being completely unnecessary (the PEP8 justification is not that valid) and extremely inconsistent (documentation, other users), it's also always been source of bugs and annoying issues (like yours). Every time I see someone using it posting something, it's either about its issues, or there's somebody else that comments complaining about it.

Comment: 1. Unless pyside/qt creates objects dynamically I'm sure. At least the code I am trying it with is the most basic pyside app possible, without dynamically created objects afaik.

2. Seeing the troubles I have already encountered and seeing other people with similar standpoints I have indeed decided not to use this feature.

Thank you for the answer nonetheless.